# Pandas DataFrame replace() doesn't work if the dataframe has nullable boolean columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

When trying to use `pandas.DataFrame.replace()` on a dataframe with several columns including boolean columns where the `boolean` (i.e. nullable) dtype has been set explicitly beforehand:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["x", "y", "z", "w"], "b": [True, False, False, True]}).astype({"b":"boolean"})
df.replace("x", "X")
```

I get the following error:

```
File "C:\users\el_caminooooo\playground\venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/boolean.py", line 265, in __init__
    "values should be boolean numpy array. Use "
TypeError: values should be boolean numpy array. Use the 'pd.array' function instead
```

Is this a pandas bug? I tested this with version 1.2.5 and 1.34 on python 3.7. Also please note both of the following work fine:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["x", "y", "z", "w"], "b": [True, False, False, True]}).astype({"b":"bool"})  # notice 'bool' instead of 'boolean'
df.replace("x", "X")
```

and:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["x", "y", "z", "w"], "b": [True, False, False, True]})
df.replace("x", "X")
```

Comment: Could you please explain what `.astype({"a": pd.api.types.pandas_dtype("string"), "b":pd.api.types.pandas_dtype("boolean")})` does? because when I remove it the code works perfectly

Comment: This is a minimal reproduction snippet. In my codebase, this error is part of a larger automated process where I parse some input data and constrain it to some pre-determined types. For example I might be parsing a CSV and setting the dtype on the 1st column to timedelta, on the 2nd column to boolean, etc. My point is, the above code should be working.

Comment: This was confirmed as a bug here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44499#issuecomment-974571493